# How to mock class and inject as a parameter with Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I am trying to mock a QueryBuilder class from typeorm because I have a function that takes in as a parameter a Querybuilder class. So I have written a code like below to mock QueryBuilder

```
const mockRepository = jest.fn<QueryBuilder<User>, []>(() => ({
    select: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    where: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    limit: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    getManyAndCount: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(
        items,
    ),
}))
```

and it complains that I should not only just mock four methods of QueryBuilder but also other 38 more methods that exist in QueryBuilder class. I obviously do not want to mock every single method so I tried using Partial to overcome it like below

```
const mockRepository = jest.fn<Partial<QueryBuilder<User>>, []>(() => ({
    select: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    where: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    limit: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    getManyAndCount: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(
        items,
    ),
}))
```

now the error is gone but the function where I would like to do Dependency Injection as the parameter causes problem.

```
service._buildQueryForQueryBuilder(mockRepository);
```

the parameter of _buildQueryForQueryBuilder takes in a QueryBuilder type and now it's complaining that other 38 methods of QueryBuilder should also be implemented. How do I only mock a few functions that I choose to and still provide correct type as the parameter of a function I would like to unit test?

Answer (score 0):

Would it still be complaining if you simply force-cast it?

```
jest.fn<QueryBuilder<User>, []>(() => ({
    select: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    where: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    limit: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    getManyAndCount: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(
        items,
    ),
} as QueryBuilder<User>))
```

Comment: What you describe as a "force cast" is a *type assertion*.